# Immediate consequence of a theorem related to spanning set/basis - linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, hamel-basis

I am going through a theorem and its corollary from a text book:

Theorem $T_0$: Let $W$ be a subspace of $R^n$, and let $B = \{v_1,...,v_p\}$ be a spanning set of $W$ containing $p$ vectors. Then any set of $p+1$ or more vectors in $W$ is a linearly dependent set.

Corollary to the above theorem : Let $W$ be subspace of $R^n$, and let $B = \{w_1,...,w_p\}$ be a basis of $W$ containing $p$ vectors. Then every basis for $W$ contains $p$ vectors.

Theorem to be proved $T_1$: Any set of fewer than $p$ vectors in $W$ does not span $W$.

The textbook claims that :
$T_1$ is equivalent to the statement that a spanning set for $W$ must contain at
least $p$ vectors. Again, this is an **immediate** consequence of theorem $T_0$.

I could not understand why it is an immediate consequence.
Can somebody help me out.

Comment: If a  spanning set for W contains less than $p$ vectors, then by theorem $T_0$  $w_1,\ldots,w_p$ is a linearly dependent set.

Comment: Theorem $T_0$ states "if a set of $p$ vectors spans, then any set with more than $p$ vectors is dependent."  This is logically equivalent to its contrapositive, which is "If a set with more than $p$ vectors is linearly independent, then a set with $p$ vectors does not span."

Comment: @ArturoMagidin. Correct statement. One doubt : Why the contrapositive is not the statement : If a set with **less** than p vectors is linearly independent, then a set with p vectors does not span. Can you point to some tutorials/books in which the contrapositive of some 'complex' statements are explained.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin. My comment is basically why the negation of 'a set with more than p vectors is linearly independent' is 'a set with more than p vectors is linearly independent'. Why not 'a set with less than p vectors is linearly independent'. This could be a naive question.

Comment: The contrapositive of "if P then Q" is "if not(Q), then not(P)". Here Q is "if the set has more than $p$ elements, then it is linearly dependent". The negation of "if R then S" is "R and not(S)", So not(Q) is "the set has more than $p$ elements and is linearly independent.". P is the statement "the set has $p$ elements and spans." I could have negated it as "either the set does not have $p$ elements or the set does not span", but this is equivalent to "if the set has $p$ elements then it does not span". because "A or B" is equivalent to "if not(A) then B". (cont)

Comment: There are other ways to parse some of the statements, but your proposal does not work. The negation of "a set with more than p elements is linearly dependent" cannot be "a set with fewer than p vectors is independent" because there is no way to parse them to make them negations of each other. If you read the first as an implication, the negation cannot be an implication. If you read the first as a conjunction, the negation cannot be a conjunction as well.  No matter how you think of the first statement (an "or", an "and", or an "if...then..."), its negation cannot have the same form.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Can you please elaborate what is meant by *because there is no way to parse them to make them negations of each other*.

Comment: I did. Both sentences have the same structure, so whether you think of the as implications or conjunctions,you have a conjunction as the negation of a conjunction, which is impossible, or you have an implication as the negation of an implication, which is also impossible. The negation of an implication is a conjunction. The negation of a conjunction is either an implication or a disjunction (every implication is a disjunction and vice versa).

Comment: In addition, you can have both a set with more than p elements that is dependent, *and* a set with fewer than p elements that is *also* dependent, in the same context. A sentence and its negation cannot both be true, simultaneously, in the same context.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a basis of a vector space is a linearly independent set and what generates that vector space. Furthermore, All bases for a finite-dimensional vector space have the same number of vectors.